# Classic ASP error '800a01ad' ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, com, activex

we have a system that wasnt designed by us, and part of that system is a classic ASP portal. The portal is currently running with no issues on one of out servers.

We want to do some development work on the portal, so we want to put it on TFS, and than work on it locally. The problem no matter what I tried  we cant make it run locally. this is what we tried:

1. import the IIS setting from the working server
2. register whatever dll we can think of
3. Pool is running with system network credentials
4. pool have 32bit enabled
5. running it using VS2012
6. The log files don't seem to have anything useful

The error:

> CAMSSession error '800a01ad'
>
> ActiveX component can't create object
>
> /StudentTest/inc/TRSSession.asp, line 17

How can I detect what is it that we are missing? I am assuming it is a dll.
We know that it is not a code issue because the website is running okay on the server.

The lines that causes the error:

```
TRSSession.Acquire GUID, RemoteIP
```

in:

```
    Dim TRSSession
    Dim GUID
    Dim RemoteIP

GUID = CStr(Request.Cookies("TRSSession"))
RemoteIP = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")

If Not IsObject(Session("TRSSession")) Then
    Set TRSSession = Server.CreateObject("CAMSSession.TRSSession")
    Call TRSSession.Constructor(Application.Value("strSvrName"), Application.Value("strDBName"))
    TRSSession.PortalServiceURI = Application.Value("PortalService")
    TRSSession.IP = RemoteIP
    TRSSession.AllowBatchMode = True
    Set Session("TRSSession") = TRSSession
    TRSSession.Acquire GUID, RemoteIP
Else
    Set TRSSession = Session("TRSSession")
End If

If GUID = "" Then
    If LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) = "on" Then
        Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "TRSSession=" & CStr(TRSSession.GUID) & "; secure; HttpOnly"
    Else
        Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "TRSSession=" & CStr(TRSSession.GUID) & "; HttpOnly"
    End If
End If

Dim TRSSessionF

If Request.QueryString("GUID") <> "" Then
    Set TRSSessionF = Server.CreateObject("CAMSSession.TRSSession")
    Call TRSSessionF.Constructor(Application.Value("strSvrName"), Application.Value("strDBName"))
    TRSSessionF.PortalServiceURI = Application.Value("PortalService")
    TRSSessionF.IP = RemoteIP
    TRSSessionF.Acquire Request.QueryString("GUID"), RemoteIP, True
    TRSSession("TermID") = TRSSessionF("TermID")
    TRSSession("TextTerm") = TRSSessionF("TextTerm")
    TRSSession("SROfferID") = TRSSessionF("SROfferID")
    TRSSession("CourseName") = TRSSessionF("CourseName")
    TRSSession("Course") = TRSSessionF("Course")
    TRSSession("FacultyID") = TRSSessionF("FacultyID")
    TRSSession("FPM") = "True"
    TRSSession("StudentName")= "<span style=""color:Red"">Faculty Preview Mode</span>"
End If

%>
```

Comment: What's on line 17???

Comment: yes, it is a DLL. plz show source code of /StudentTest/inc/TRSSession.asp

Comment: Hey, I added the TRSSession.asp code in the post, thank you!

Comment: We still don't know what line the error is pointing to.

Comment: The error is pointing to: TRSSession.Acquire GUID, RemoteIP

Comment: What is `TRSSession.Acquire()` doing? It looks as though the `CAMSSession.TRSSession` COM object (`TRSSession`) is raising the error, so the reference it is looking for is likely buried inside it's codebase.

Comment: If I was to guess it looks like it belongs to this system - [CAMS Enterprise ERP](https://www.threeriverssystems.com/software/cams-enterprise/)

Comment: @user1050491 did you ever manage to resolve this? Another user is having the [exact same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361633/activex-component-cannot-create-object?noredirect=1&lq=1). Any insights you gleaned would be useful, maybe even leave an answer on this question that could potentially help others?